# Can I stream multiple live videos with one adobe media server at one time?

Tags: flash, video-streaming, adobe, media, live-streaming

If I have 2 video sources in 2 PCs, can I use one adobe media server to stream both concurrently? I am using flash media encoder on each PC

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can use AMS to stream two live streams in the same time, it is made for that.